# Compare title on item, if it exists I want to add a new file with eg. v2 at the end

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I'm checking if a list item exist in a folder:

```
 SPFolder folder = site.RootWeb.GetFolder(folderUrl);
                    if (folder.ItemCount > 0)
                    {
                        SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
                        query.Folder = folder;
                        SPListItemCollection listitem = list.GetItems(query); 

                        foreach (SPListItem item in listitem)
                        {
                           if (item.Title.Equals("ItemTitle")) {
                              // Add a new item with Title: ItemTitle_v2
                           }
                        }
                    }
```

If a item exist, I first check if the title is eg. "ItemTitle". If it is I add a new item with "_v2" at the end: "ItemTitle_v2". But I also want to check if a _v2,3,4,5,6 etc exists. How can I do this?

Comment: You have not tried any code relating to actual question! Show us what logic did you try to match and check existence of files.

Comment: item.Title.Equals("ItemTitle") ?

Comment: What do you expect code to do if it finds item *ItemTitle_v2*, do you want to insert *ItemTitle_v3* in such case?

Comment: Yeah that's exactly what I want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by using this:

```
private string AppendFileNumberIfExists(SPWeb rootWeb, SPFolder folder, string file)
    {
        if (rootWeb.GetFile(file).Exists) 
        {
            string fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file); // The file name with no extension. 
            int fileVersionNumber = 0;

            do
            {
                var version = "_v";
                fileVersionNumber += 1;
                file = SPUrlUtility.CombineUrl(folder.Url, 
                            string.Format("{0}{1}{2}{3}", 
                                            fileName,
                                            version,
                                            fileVersionNumber,
                                            ".csv" ));       
            }
            while (rootWeb.GetFile(file).Exists); // As long as the file name exists, keep looping. 
        }
        return file;
 }
```

(Inspired by: [http://www.donationcoder.com/forum/index.php?topic=38536.0](http://Rename%20file))

Answer (score 0):

Check code below. I have put it on .NET Fiddle so you can execute and verify. I have not used SP classes but logic is common in any case.

https://dotnetfiddle.net/hf85Jo.

```
public static void Main()
{
    var source = new List<ListItem>();
    source.Add(new ListItem { Title = "ItemTitle" });
    source.Add(new ListItem { Title = "ItemTitle_v2" });
    source.Add(new ListItem { Title = "ItemTitle_v3" });
    source.Add(new ListItem { Title = "OtherTitle" });

    var target = new List<ListItem>();
    target.AddRange(source); // Do not assign source directly, that will cause error.

    foreach(var item in source)
    {
        if(item.Title == "ItemTitle")
        {
            var newTitle = GetItemTitle(target, "ItemTitle");
            target.Add(new ListItem { Title = newTitle });
        }
    }
}

private static string GetItemTitle(IList<ListItem> destList, string titleToCheck)
{
    int verNum;

    // Get the last added item with matching title
    var match = destList.Last(s => s.Title.StartsWith(titleToCheck));

    // Check if there are items with versioned title
    if(match.Title.ToLower().Contains("_v"))
    {
        // Get the version string
        string verStr = match.Title.Split('_')[1];
        // Get the version number
        string verNo = verStr.ToLower().Replace("v", string.Empty);
        if(int.TryParse(verNo, out verNum))
        {
            verNum++;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        verNum = 2;
    }

    return string.Format("{0}_v{1}", titleToCheck, verNum);
}
```